# "Open command window here" with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, cmd.exe

Is there a way to open a command window, with current path as the current Explorer folder, with a keyboard shortcut?

Something like:

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT CLICK</kbd>, Click on "Open window command here"

but with a simple keyboard shortcut?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do it out of the box, but this does the trick with [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/), with <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>:

```
#s::
Sendmode INPUT
Send {shift down}
Click,,Right
send {shift up}
Send,F
Return
```

Answer (score 5):

When viewing the desired folder in Explorer you can also type `cmd` in the address bar and press enter.  This will open a cmd window at that location.  You can also use `ALT`+`D` to focus the address bar if you don't want to take your hands off the keyboard.

Comment: Wow, this is really great, I didn't know the "write `cmd` in address bar" trick! (Remark : ALT D doesn't work for me, but F4 does)